# Shape And Selector is not working

Tags: android, css, xml

In my android application want my button to be green and rounded rectangle and when someone press the button it should change color to grey. So I have created an XML file with selector and give it to shape of rounded rectangle but problem is when I start my application the color is not green by default its transparent. Moreover when I press the button it shows rectangle shape so I think shapre is also not working. This is my Primary color:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#669900</color>
```

My custom_button.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
                <corners
                    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
                <corners
                    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

Also I have made a XML file for gradient which is gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <gradient android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#880f0f10"
                android:centerColor="#880d0d0f"
                android:endColor="#885d5d5e"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your rectangles to be rounded, try something like the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners
                    android:radius="5dp"/>
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"   
                    android:color="@color/border_of_rectangle"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/color_inside_rectangle"/>
           </shape>
       </item>
   </layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've made something similar before here is how i did it

button.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

button_default.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/radius" />
    <solid
        android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        />
</shape>
```

button_pressed.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/radius" />
    <solid
        android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        />
</shape>
```

values/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/BlueButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BlueButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I'm also guessing that you might need to change the text color so here is the file 
button_text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent" android:state_focused="true" />
</selector>
```